# How to get property value in Handlebars/Mustache?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache

I have such an hierarchy in JS on page, simplified for reading:

```
window.dx = {};
window.dx.messages = {};
window.dx.messages.someMessage = "someMessage";
window.searchResults.transfers = [{"id": 1, ...}, ...];
window.searchResults.isFeatureEnabled = true;
```

and template, where using Mustache we have to render values:

```
<a role="button" href="#blablablaToggle{{id}}"</a>
{{#if ../isFeatureEnabled}}
<a role="button" href="#anotherBlaBlaToggle{{id}}" data-toggle-text="{{../../../dx.messages.someMessage}}"></a>
{{/if}}
```

Everything renders fine, except data in `data-toggle-text` attribute - as a result on rendered page I have attribute without value. Could someone help or suggest what is wrong with getting message text value from objects hierarchy? Thanks a lot!

Comment: change {{../../../dx.messages.someMessage}} to ../../../{{dx.messages.someMessage}}

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but in such way I have smth like data-toggle-text="../../../"

Comment: Made workaround with custom Mustache-helper - but the question about scopes still opened

Comment: What data object are you passing to your template?